# Reading from BufferedReader throws exception as stream closed after creating a new BufferedReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader, ioexception

Following is a method which takes input from user and returns the response.

```
private String getValueFromUser(String propertyValue){
    String response = ""; 
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))){
        response = br.readLine();
        if (response.equals("")){
            return propertyValue;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}
```

This method when executed runs fine for first call but throws the following exception in the subsequent calls.

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:170)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:336)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
at com.ripple.utility.ConfigurationUtility.getValueFromUser(ConfigurationUtility.java:119)
at com.ripple.utility.ConfigurationUtility.createPropertiesDTO(ConfigurationUtility.java:108)
at com.ripple.utility.ConfigurationUtility.setProperties(ConfigurationUtility.java:169)
at com.ripple.utility.ConfigurationUtility.main(ConfigurationUtility.java:191)
```

Can someone please help in explaining the problem with the code ?

Comment: You don't need to close the System.in but you do need to retain a buffer as it could read as much data as is available not just the minimum you need right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `BufferedReader` gets closed at the end of the try-with-resources block, `System.in` is also closed and it can't be reopened.

You should open the reader once and keep it open somewhere where you can use it until your program is finished.

Comment: @ShubhenduPramanik because you ran it only once?

Comment: Creating buffered reader like the one shown below worked:
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new NoCloseInputStream(System.in)))){}